# Facebook c# sdk automatic user login and "like"

Tags: c#, facebook, sdk

I would made a very simple thing using Facebook c# sdk, but couldn't find anywhere if it's possible.
If I have username and password of a user, I could put an automatically a "like" on a specific page, without any prompt to the end user? My application doesn't have a GUI and I would made it all automatic.

Comment: Do you want to tell Facebook the user "likes" the page? Or do you just want to display the button so they can click it if they want?

Comment: Sounds kinda shady, are you trying to get people to automatically like a page, without their knowing/consent?

Comment: @stuartmclark: people register to my system inserting fb username and password, then using sensors they could place "i like" automatically on some page

Comment: @ben: the first one, i don't have i GUI, i just want to tell to facebook that a user likes a page

Comment: I don't think Facebook want you to do that, that's why they don't provide a way.

Comment: i see that in 2010 there was some project that made it, i don't know if API has changed. this is only a way to connect real world to facebook: imagine to touch an apple and automatically see in your profile "i like apple" (the user inserted his credential before and he knows that touching the apple will generate the facebook action, so there is no privacy issue o something else)

Comment: Have you managed to get ANYONE to enter their FB username and password into your application? I think you will find that no-one will do that. Are you trying to implement something similar to a "Like" button that is hosted on a non-Facebook site and it automatically recognises the user?

Comment: users will insert their creadential, this is not a problem. I use RFID technology and i would make something similar to this [http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xUv0GU5rfHg]. There is no GUI, there is only interaction with real things, so no buttons, no viruses o something like that.

Comment: I would highly doubt they're storing username/password on those RFIDs as the announcer said (probably a dumbed-down version of the script that the announcer read, or a mistranslation from the technical people to the production people).  They're probably just storing the OAUTH's user access token.  You are allowed to store a user's OAUTH token, but not a username password.

Comment: thank you for your answer DMCS. In this way my users need a self-station to make login in the "standard way" and take the rfid tag associated, then i could save their OAUTH user access token and use it for publish every "I like" that they make in the real world. Is it correct?

Answer (score 2):

I do believe it is against Facebook policy for you to collect Facebook usernames and Facebook passwords.  **I highly suggest you consult with your corporate attorney before proceeding.**

Comment: this is not my problem, i asked for a technical problem. There i way to make system-to-system authentication and put an "i like"?

Comment: @user1197041 - but it Is your problem because if you are found to be violating policy it will be **YOUR** account that is disabled.

Comment: Then then answer is "No". You are unable to put a like without authenticating the user using oauth2.